# Conflict of python versions and winerror 5

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I installed Python 3.9 and when in cmd I use python3 --version it gives python 3.10.2.
It could be the reason for WinError 5 access denied when I try to install tensorflow?

Comment: Please read https://xyproblem.info/

Answer (score 0):

You most likely installed multiple Python versions. Open up your cmd, run `where python3`, delete the ones you don't want.

Comment: I follow your advice and in the folder there is Python 3.10.exe but I cannot delete. Also there is not Python 3.9

Comment: So only python 3.10 showed up? That means you only installed python 3.10...how did you install the python 3.9?

Comment: I downloaded the installer from Python website.. In the control panel there is no Python 3.10, there is only Python 3.9